# Catching exception types twice

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Can we catch an exception type twice in the main method with different messages? I want to print out a different warning.

### Ex:

```
 try {
    // some code
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Wrong input!"); 
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("No valid number!"); 
 }
```

Comment: Looks like the XY problem.  What is it that you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: Why you're doing this?

Comment: what is the difference between "Wrong input!" and "No valid number!" ?

Comment: I wrote my own excepcion and throw it for different faults and now I want to explan in the catch statement which fault it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand your comments you want to display the right message for your exception:

```
 try {
    // some code
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot catch the same exception type (like `NumberFormatException`) twice. I suggest you catch it once but in the catch block, you print two messages instead.

Comment: and how can I decide when I print which message?

Comment: You tell me. How can you decide based on the exception type, if that type is the same. You cannot decide based on the exception type. You need a variable or something else. That's why I said 'you tell me'.

Comment: perhabs through the message, when I trow the exception? But I don't know it, that's why i'm asking

Comment: Yes, this you can do. `throw new Exception ("message 1")` and `throw new Exception ("message 2")` Then in the catch block use the Exception's `getMessage()` method.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage%28%29

Answer (score 0):

You can´t catch the same exception twice.

What you can do is to throw a custom exception in your code and catch it if you want a different behaviour.

```
try{
   ...
   throw new YourException(yourMessage);
}catch(YourException e){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can´t catch the same exception twice.

Consider the following example,

```
try {

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    throw new SampleException(e);

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Here,

Both handlers print an error message. The second handler does nothing else. By catching any IOException that's not caught by the first handler, it allows the program to continue executing.

The first handler, in addition to printing a message, throws a user-defined exception.